# Innertext not picking up changes to webpage

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to pull data from a webpage created in ASP.NET maker.
The page is basically a large table.

When I make changes to the table, the changes appear on the page and in the html code.  The changes also appear when I export the webpage to an excel sheet.  However, the changes do not appear when I scrape the webpage with an inntertext method.

```
Dim htmlTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmltables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlcell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim rowNum As Long, colNum As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer




    'Note: htmltable(s) is collection of elements not a single element.
    Set htmltables = htmlPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each htmlTable In htmltables
        'Debug.Print htmlTable.className

        x = 1
        For Each htmlRow In htmlTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            'Debug.Print vbTab & htmlRow.innertext

            y = 1
            '//This prints out any level below the "tr" element
            For Each htmlcell In htmlRow.Children
                'Debug.Print vbTab & htmlcell.innertext

                Sheet3.Activate

                Cells(x, y) = htmlcell.innertext

            y = y + 1
            Next htmlcell

        x = x + 1
        Next htmlRow

    Next htmlTable
```

Has anyone every experienced something like this before?  I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Is this webpage public? Care to share a link ?

Comment: "When I make changes to the table" - where/how are you making these changes?

Comment: ^^ As above. Also, share the full code please.

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting a cached version of the page, but you don't show us how you get the content.  Try adding some random querystring parameter on the end of the URL and see if that fixes it.   Something like `"http://yourUrlHere.asp?x=" & Rnd() * 1000000`

Comment: The page is not public. I think you are right about the cached.  I closed all of my browsers, tried again and it worked. How can I make sure the cache is empty when I run the code?

Comment: See @TimWilliams comment. You can try to avoid being served cached page via amending url.

Comment: If you show how you make the call to the page someone can help you make a change to that.